# Pandas: How to select rows with [ ] in any of 2 selected column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe created by mapping an existing dataframe
with a dictionary of key values and list of data for each of them.

The dataframe I have at the end is similar to that (but with 1500 rows):

```
   N  A                 B         C                   D
0  1  [value1, value2]  [value8]  []                  [value18]
1  2  [value3]          [value9]  [value13, value14]  []
2  3  [value4, value5]  [value10] [value15]           [value19]
3  4  [value6]          [value11] [value16]           [value20]
4  5  [value7]          [value12] [value17]           []
```

Some of the rows contains one or more [ ] which are apparently more considered as empty list than a Nan value or a '[]' string.
Is it possible to get the rows when there is [ ] missing value in column C or D?

expected output:

```
   N  A                 B         C                   D
0  1  [value1, value2]  [value8]  []                  [value18]
1  2  [value3]          [value9]  [value13, value14]  []
4  5  [value7]          [value12] [value17]           []
```

I have tried 
df2 = df1[pd.isnull(df1).any(axis=1)]
without success

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this.  Just get the len of each list in the columns, then select where the len is 0.

```
df1['c_len'] = df1.c.apply(len)
df1['d_len'] = df1.d.apply(len)
df1[(df1.c_len == 0) | (df1.d_len == 0)]
```